# Connect to Cloud SQL using SSL

Tags: google-cloud-sql, teiid

I am trying to connect to a CloudSQL instance using the certificates provided by google namely "client-cert.pem", "client-key.pem" and "server-ca.pem".

Can someone suggest what to keep in keystore and what in truststore for SSL connection using jdbc.

The client I am using is teiid.

P.S. - I tried importing client-cert.pem into keystore by converting it into p12 file, also imported it in cacerts of jdk, but nothing is working in my case. For truststore I imported server-ca.pem into a seperate keystore.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a IP addresses to authorized network list of your Cloud SQL instance, using SSL certificates:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-tools

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-rsa-files-using-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to connect via SSL, I suggest you take a look at the [Cloud SQL JDBC SocketFactory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory). This SocketFactory provides SSL connections to a Cloud SQL instance, authenticated with IAM credentials.

If you want to manually specify certificates you've created directly to the JDBC driver, you can follow these instructions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) to configure the system properties to do so. .

Comment: Thanks for the info, currently I am using cloudsql proxy to achieve the same. Will look into JDBC Socket factory too..

Comment: If you are using the Cloud SQL proxy, you'll be unable to use a client/server certificate combo. This is because the proxy only supports SSL between itself and the instance, not between the application and the proxy itself.